# C# event subscription in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts

So, in visual studio, if you type something like this:

```
retryExecutor.Retrying +=
```

Then a little tooltip thing pops up saying that you can press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to turn it into this:

```
retryExecutor.Retrying+= new EventHandler(retryExecutor_Retrying);
```

Then if you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, it generates:

```
void retryExecutor_Retrying(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Of course, this is very useful. But I find myself more often needing a construction like so:

```
retryExecutor.Retrying += (o, e) =>
{

};
```

So, is there anyway to add a new shortcut, or at least change the functionality of pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

Comment: Why do you prefer inline methods to ones that are explicitly defined in the source file *as a matter of general course*? I certainly understand that they are useful sometimes, but it strikes me as strange that you generally use the latter more often than the former.

Comment: Well, if possible, I try to use the explicitly defined ones. But in the type of coding I usually do, I find it necessary to use inline methods. Sometimes, its just cleaner to do it this way too, e.g. if there's just one statement you want to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always crate and use IntelliSense code snipppets. Read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=VS.100%29.aspx